# How to calculate cummulative sum in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a tableau server. I have Dimension **State** and **City**, and I have measures **Person Score1** and **Person Score2**. Table1 shows the sum of values of `Person Score1` and `Person Score2` falling into their corresponding `State` and `City`. I need to find values in **KS** column.

```
TABLE1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  State  |  City  | Sum(Person Score1)| SUM(Person Score2) |  KS         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  S1     |  C1    | 1500              | 2200               |             |
|         |----------------------------------------------------------------
|         |  C2    | 2300              | 2000               |             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  S2     |  C12   | 7900              | 1000               |             |
|         |----------------------------------------------------------------
|         |  C23   | 1200              | 3400               |             |
|         |----------------------------------------------------------------
|         |  C21   | 5400              | 2400               |             |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ..     | ..     | ..                |  ..                |             |
|  ..     | ..     | ..                |  ..                |             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is how I need to derive the **KS** value -
Use Table2.x for references.So lets say for State `S1` and City `C1` I have 6 records and the values for Person scores are shown in Table2.x. If you sum these values they will be equal to the value provided in table1 i.e. `SUM(Person Score1) and SUM(Person Score2)`.
Column `Cum PS1` is cummulative sum of `Person Score1`, column `Cum PS2` is cummulative sum of `Person Score2` and column `AbsD` is `|Cum PS1 - Cum PS2|`.
The `KS` value for `S1` and `C1` is `MAX(AbsD)` i.e. in Table2.1 it is **700** and in Table2.2 it is **750**.

> P.s. Table2.x are just for reference, I only want Table1 in Workbook.

```
TABLE2.1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|State|City| Person| Person|Cum PS1         |Cum PS2         |  AbsD          |
|     |    | Score1| Score2|                |                |                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     |    | 200   | 600   |(200+0  =)200   |(600+0=)600     |(600-200=)  400 |    
|     |    | 400   | 150   |(200+400=)600   |(600+150=)750   |(750-600=)  150 |
|S1   | C1 | 300   | 300   |(600+300=)900   |(750+300=)1050  |(1050-900=) 150 |
|     |    | 100   | 450   |(900+100=)1000  |(1050+450=)1500 |(1500-1000=)500 |
|     |    | 250   | 400   |(1000+250=)1250 |(1500+400)=1900 |(1900-1250=)650 |
|     |    | 250   | 300   |(1250+250=)1500 |(1900+300=)2200 |(2200-1500=)700 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------





TABLE2.2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|State|City| Person| Person|Cum PS1        |Cum PS2        |  AbsD          |
|     |    | Score1| Score2|               |               |                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     |    | 250   | 600   |(0+250=)    250|(0+600=)    600|(600-250=)  350 |    
|     |    | 300   | 150   |(300+250=)  550|(600+150=)  750|(750-550=)  200 |
|S1   | C1 | 200   | 300   |(550+200=)  750|(750+300=) 1050|(1050-750=) 300 |
|     |    | 200   | 650   |(750+200=)  950|(1050+650=)1700|(1700-950=) 750 |
|     |    | 300   | 200   |(950+300=) 1250|(1700+200=)1900|(1900-1250=)650 |
|     |    | 250   | 300   |(1250+300=)1500|(1900+300=)2200|(2200-1500=)700 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make Table1 as a visual in tableau? Is it possible to achieve this in Tableau server ?

Comment: read the section in the online help about Table Calculations. (and also experiment with right clicking on your measure fields that you are using on shelves and choosing from the Quick Table Calcs)

Comment: I guess you might be pointing towards ``PREVIOUS_VALUE`` or ``RUNNING_SUM`` functions. You are right I can perform those two for ``Table2`` in my question. But ``Table2`` is just for reference, it doesn't exist in my workbooks. Can you provide solution for ``Table1`` ?

Comment: Table Calcs are relative to specific dimensions.  Quick Table calcs usually default to "Table Across" or "Table Down" depending on the specific layout.  You likely need to click "Edit Table Calculation" and select which dimensions are used in computing the table calculation.

Comment: @tagyoureit and @Alex Blakemore This is what I got from tableau documentation - _A table calculation is a transformation you apply to the values in a visualization. They are calculated based on what is currently in the visualization and do not consider any measures or dimensions that are filtered out of the visualization._  In my question `Person Score1` and `Person Score2` is not in the visualization rather I have `Sum(Person Score1)` and `Sum(Person Score2)` in the visualization.   I believe there is a subtle difference between what you are saying and what is in the question.

Comment: Can you provide some further sample raw data?  Assuming that the last value isn't always going to be the value that is the correct value and seeing some other sample data would help.

Comment: @tagyoureit added another example table -`Table2.2`. Hope that helps and let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: This is a bit tricky to do in Tableau because you need to use a running_sum (table calc) within each city/state combination but then you need to use LoD (Level of Detail) to let Tableau when to stop calculating for a particular city/state.  Unfortunately, you can't use Table Calcs inside of LoDs today.

My suggestion would be to do part of the work (running sum, possibly difference of the running sum) before bringing this into Tableau.

If you do that, you could use either Table Calcs or LoDs without needing to combine them in Tableau.